# Messing with depth multiplier in Google's Object Detection API

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

Has anyone tryed to mess with the depth_multiplier variable,in the config files, during a training with Google's Object Detection API?? In my understanding if you change the value of this variable (1.0 by default) you can't make use of fine tuning from the already provided pre-trained models. Am i correct? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you are correct... if you were to do this, you'd have to train from scratch, or first train an Imagenet classifier with the same base architecture and fine tune from that.

Comment: Is there any potential benefit in changing the depth multiplier?

Comment: Choosing a depth multiplier less than 1 would make your network thiner. It might  be beneficial if you'd like to speed up your inference time or reduce the number of parameters. On the opposite, with a depth multiplier greater than 1, you would increase the capacity of the network at the cost of latency.